# please help choose mosfet, npn, pnp, diode for my circuit

Tags: mosfet, diodes, constant-current, charge-pump

I developed a circuit which uses charge pump to supply a current mirror.

Simulation works, I was able to get 40V and constant 10 mA at load < 4k.

I breadboarded each charge pump and current mirror circuit and each worked.

But when I supply charge pump to current mirror, current mirror load became weird.

I think is because my mosfet, pnp, npn cannot handle 40V?

Can anyone choose correct parts for me, or tell me what to look for in datasheet?

Thank you.

---

actually I am able to get square wave signal with current mirror supplied by charge pump, but signal is really noisy. when I supplied with only 12V, signal was clear.

I think problem is selection of 2n3906 or IRFH530, because I tested with Vsupply = C5 = about 20V, signal was clear.

If Vsupply = C7 = about 27V, signal is noisy.

Then I tested with 27V power supply instead of charge pump, signal disappear.

So I think my current mirror cannot handle Vsupply > 27V.

How can I choose correct pnp and mosfet.

fE is uF
[image: circuit]

Answer (score 1):

Which mosfet are using? You are saying IRFH530, but there is no such part. There is IRF530, which is rated for 100 volts and should be fine, and IRFH5300, which is only rated at 30 volts, and will not work above 30 volts.

Also, debugging two circuits at once is hard. You seem to have two problems: noisy output and non-working at high voltage. So:

(1) Forget about charge pump temporarily. Supply 40 volts from lab power supply (or from many batteries if you do not have one). Debug your current mirror until it works.

(2) Once you are 100% sure that your current mirror is fine, start debugging the charge pump. Most likely, it will give you voltage which is too noisy or too low -- you will have to use a scope to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I discovered what is the problem.  Your schematic shows that you are using IRFH5300, which (per theamk), is only good to 30v! Using IRF530 should solve your problem.